# Unix command ls -lrt giving unexpected results

Tags: linux, ls

So I was doing my work and I needed to list some particular files in a folder.
I typed 
`ls -lrt *ABCD*201604*` 
and it returned 
`*ABCD*201604* not found`.

Then to see if such files actually were there or not I did `ls -lrt` and found that there were such files.

So next I copied `ABCD` and `201604` from listed files while typing command `ls -lrt *ABCD*201604*` and that worked!

I compared both of my commands to see if I did any mistake but found that both were exactly same. Any explanation for such behavior?

One which I wrote:

```
$ ls -lrt *RFPTDW*20160425*
*RFPTDW*20160425* not found
```

One which I copied:

```
$ ls -lrt *RFPTDW*20160425*
RFPTDW107_01_01_20160425_1526.txt
RFPTDW059_01_01_20160425_1527.txt
```

In second output I have omitted other details but filename.

Comment: `*abcd*201604*` matches files that have `abcd` followed by `201604` in them somewhere. it doesn't match ACROSS files names. onlyl single files that have both string patterns in them, in that order. e.g. `201604abcd.txt` won't match, nor will `abcd.txt` or `201604.txt`, but `abcdfoobar201604bazqux.txt` will

Comment: Copy and paste the exact commands and output from your terminal so we can see. It's likely something subtle that is being lost in your writeup. (I notice that you said `ls -lrt *ABCD*201604*` printed `*ABCD*20160425* not found` which isn't right due to the extra `25`. It's best to avoid retyping things to avoid subtle discrepancies like this.)

Comment: @JohnKugelman, sorry about that. It was just for illustration. I will add exact commands and output.

Comment: @MarcB, no, this is not the case. Both commands are same but one gives output (Which I copied from file name itself) whereas other shows no result (Which I typed by keyboard).

Answer (score 3):

The shell is responsible for expanding the globs on the command line. The command executed doesn't see those wildcard characters: it sees the expanded arguments.

When you want to see how those are expanded, try prepending the command you want with `echo`. Like such:

```
$ touch ABCD
$ touch 201604
$ touch foo_ABCD_bar_201604_baz
$ echo ls -lrt *ABCD*
ls -lrt ABCD foo_ABCD_bar_201604_baz
$ echo ls -lrt *201604*
ls -lrt 201604 foo_ABCD_bar_201604_baz
$ echo ls -lrt *ABCD*201604*
ls -lrt foo_ABCD_bar_201604_baz
$ rm foo_ABCD_bar_201604_baz
$ echo ls -lrt *ABCD*201604*
ls -lrt *ABCD*201604*
```

Notice that on the last line, the glob no longer expands to a filename, so the `ls` command would be handed the argument `*ABCD*201604*`, which names a file that does not exist.

Edit:

If you prepend `echo` to your actual commands, I expect that your result will be

```
$ echo ls -lrt *RFPTDW*20160425*
ls -lrt *RFPTDW*20160425*
```

in the first case, and

```
$ echo ls -lrt *RFPTDW*20160425*
ls -lrt RFPTDW107_01_01_20160425_1526.txt RFPTDW059_01_01_20160425_1527.txt
```

in the second case. In the first case, the files do not exist, so the glob does not expand to anything. In the second case, some files match the glob, and so the shell can expand it.

Comment: I have added my case. Can you please relate it to  your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes character encoding is the problem. There are characters in Unicode which are looking quite the same as the ASCII ones (so called homoglyphs). So maybe there are "special" characters which only work when you copy paste them.

Also ASCII characters are sometimes hard to distinguish like 0-O (Zero, Letter O), or 1-`l` (One and Letter L)

Comment: Are you saying that if file name is in UTF-8 encoding it won't be listed using command I type?
And its definitely not the case of homoglyphs.

Comment: @Deepak jha No, it will be listed. But if there is a character which e.g. looks like A but is not ASCII A, it will not work if you type `ls *A*`, but will work if you copy that character (which will look like `ls *A*`, but actually isn't)